Creating ScriptableObject through script
I need to create a ScriptableObject through script, So I used AssetDatabase.CreateAsset but it creates inside project folders only.
So is there a way to create the ScriptableObject through script outside project folders?
And if there are no other ways, how can I convert the choosen folder path to a suitable path for AssetDatabase.CreateAsset?
like E:/Projects/Time System/Assets/ChoosenFolder to Assets/ChoosenFolder.
I'm choosing the folder by string path = EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel("Choose Folder", "", "");

Why not create it in the project folder first and use something like https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FileUtil.MoveFileOrDirectory.html next?

what's more important to me right now is converting the choosen folder path to a suitable path for AssetDatabase.CreateAsset, but it's good idea @Zibelas

There is no reason. Use a fixed, temporary path for AssetDatabase.CreateAsset and pass the path of EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel to the FileUtil.MoveFileOrDirectory with the fixed temp path and the users chosen one.

Yes that's for creating the scriptable object outside the project but I need to cover all possibilities, for creating outside I will create the scriptable object at "Assets/" then moving it to where ever I chose by EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel, but if the user chose a folder inside the project by EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel I can't use the path of it with AssetDatabase.CreateAsset, for example, if the user chose Created Items folder inside folder assets it will appear like this E:/Projects/Time System/Assets/Created Items and AssetDatabase.CreateAsset will refuse to create to it

so the path E:/Projects/Time System/Assets/Created Items should be converted to this Assets/Created Items that's what I mentioned as being more important to me

It does not matter which folder the user chooses. You first create it like under assets/temp and move it to whatever directory the users picks. The file move accepts a full path, so you don't need to modify it at all

This is not what I mean, AssetDatabase.CreateAsset doesn't accept path like that E:/Projects/Time System/Assets/Created Items which the path is created when I chose the folder by EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel so I need to convert this path E:/Projects/Time System/Assets/Created Items to this Assets/Created Items

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
